# Initialize Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I need to initialize my membership provider, thus I start from calling it like this:

```
Public Overrides Sub Initialize(name As String, config As NameValueCollection)
            Dim myNewAsp As New AspNetSqlProvider
            If config Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("config")
            If name Is Nothing OrElse name.Length = 0 Then name =" AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(config("description")) Then
                config.Remove("description")
                config.Add("system.web/Membership", name)
            End If
            MyBase.Initialize(name, config)
```

And I call it from my code behind:

```
Dim SC As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection = New System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
            membershipProviderWareHouse.Initialize("AspNetSqlMembershipProvider", SC)
```

In my Web.Config file I have:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
      <providers >
        <clear/>
        <add
          name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionStringName="TMPApplicationServices"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          passwordFormat="Hashed"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
          passwordStrengthRegularExpression="(?=^.{8,20}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^])(?!.*\s).*$"
          requiresUniqueEmail="true"
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
          minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
          minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
          passwordAttemptWindow="10"
          applicationName="/" />

      </providers>
    </membership>
```

As a conclusion, what I want is to get the `passwordFormat` which declared in my `web.config` file.
I'm trying to get the `passwordFormat` with the following command:

```
Dim myMemPass As New MembershipPasswordFormat
```

But what I get is the `clear(0)` value and not the `Hashed(1)` which is declared in my web.config.
I really don't know what I'm doing wrong (because it is obvious that something is wrong here).
May I have an assistance?

*** ADDITIONAL INFORMATION***

```
Public membershipProviderWareHouse As New AspNetSqlMembershipProvider
```

That is for `membershipProviderWareHouse` which I forgot it.

I have made another call for the initialization:

```
    Dim membershipSection As Web.Configuration.MembershipSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/membership")
    Dim sqlProviderName As String = "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
    Dim providerConfig As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection = New System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
    providerConfig.Add("AspNetSqlMembershipProvider", (DBNull.Value).ToString)
    membershipProviderWareHouse.Initialize(sqlProviderName, providerConfig)
```

Which doesn't seams to work either.

Comment: Where in code behind and why do you have to explicitly initialize your provider?

Comment: In the registration page. It is important to initialize my provider because I'm not follow the registration as giving it, but I use something else... I making a combine from the provider and my needs. But I don't thing that is the issue here... I have made something wrong in the initialization but I can't see where I made it. I use very well the connection strings but I can't use the `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider`

Comment: I do not see your code reading the config value and setting it. You are presuming it will just read from the configuration? How?

Comment: I said that I made something wrong... is it possible to correct me?

Comment: Your `SC` doesn't seem to load any data. You are just initializing a new collection.

Comment: Yes that is true... do you know how to correct it?

Comment: Please post your entire code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45125/discussion-between-lefteris-gkinis-and-alexander)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what I was looking for.

Dim cfg As System.Configuration.Configuration = _
                      WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath)
        '
        ' Get encryption and decryption key information from the configuration.
        Dim membSection As New MembershipSection

```
    Dim srvHandler As New ServerHandler
    Dim aspProvider As New MyNewAspNetSqlMembershipProvider

    membSection = CType(cfg.GetSection("system.web/membership"), MembershipSection)
    membSection.SectionInformation.ConfigSource = "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
    machineKey = CType(cfg.GetSection("system.web/machineKey"), MachineKeySection)


    Dim keys As New ArrayList()
    Dim values As New ArrayList()
    Dim count As Integer = membSection.Providers.Item(0).Parameters.Keys.Count
    For r As Integer = 0 To count - 1
        keys.Add(membSection.Providers.Item(0).Parameters.Keys.Item(r))
        values.Add(membSection.Providers.Item(0).Parameters.GetValues(r))
    Next
```

Using this code I get all the values (and the names) of the `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` which is declared in web.config file.
That is for use from anyone wants to use it.
Thank you very much for the assistance from @Alexander